# Faster version of 'pygame.event.get()'. Why are events being missed and why are the events delayed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, pygame

I'm making an Asteroidz clone in pygame and have two `for event in pygame.event.get()` loops, one for checking an exit request and wether the game should have started by pressing spacebar, then further in the game as to try and limit the player from holding spacebar down and continuously shooting. The relevent code for my `check_input` function, which is run once every loop, is below;

```
def check_input(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #NOT CHECKING THIS FAST ENOUGH, WHOLE PROCESS IS TOO SLOW
        if (event.type == pygame.KEYUP) and (event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
            print ('boop')
            self.shootThrottle = 0

    if self.shootThrottle == 0:
        self.shootThrottle += 1
        bullets.add(Bullet(self.shape[0][0],self.shape[0][1], self.angle))

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.angle -= 7
        self.rotate(-7)
    elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.angle += 7
        self.rotate(7)

    if self.angle > 360:
        self.angle -= 360
    elif self.angle < 0:
        self.angle += 360

    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.accelerate()
    elif key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        self.decelerate()
```

I am using `shootThrottle` as a means to try stop bullets from being shot until spacebar has been let go. This system works, but due to the `for event in pygame.event.get()` being too slow, it doesn't function properly.

Any help is massively appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [...] and have **two** for event in `pygame.event.get()` loops [..]"

That's the issue. [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. See the documentation:

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. [...]

If `pygame.event.get()` is called in multiple event loops, only one loop receives the events, but never all loops receive all events. As a result, some events appear to be missed.

Get the events once per frame and use them in multiple loops or pass the list or events to functions and methods where they are handled:

```py
def handle_events(events):
    for event in events:
        # [...]

while run:

    event_list = pygame.event.get()

    # [...]

    # 1st event loop
    for event in event_list:
        # [...]

    # [...]

    # 2nd event loop
    for event in event_list:
        # [...]

    # [...]

    # function which handles events
    handle_events(event_list)
```