# Swap ship image on keypress in pygame space invaders

Tags: python, image, pygame

I want to have alternate characters in space invaders game using pygame. I want the game to switch ship to ship 1 if I press 1 and switch to ship 2 if I press 2 and so forth.

I have tried altering self.image in my ship.py file such that:

```py
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.K_1:
              self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship1.bmp')
              self.image.get_rect()
         elif event.type == pygame.K_2:
              self.image == pygame.image.load('images/ship2.bmp')
              self.image.get_rect()
```

but this returns a few errors in my main alien invasion program in regard to the ship class.

below is my working code for the static image that loads which is also the code I attempted to alter with the if and elif statements. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. If it helps I am a very nooby coder.

```py
class Ship(Sprite):
    """A class to manage the ship."""
 
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
"this returns a few errors" is not a problem specification.  Asking us to visually diagnose code out of context is usually fruitless for those of us who would help, and it's useless to the archive -- which, after all, is the site's charter purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction `self.image.get_rect()` does nothing at all. You must set the attribute `rect`. I recommend centering the new image at the center of the current image:

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
```

---

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. See the documentation:

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. [...]

See als [Faster version of 'pygame.event.get()'. Why are events being missed and why are the events delayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086113/faster-version-of-pygame-event-get-why-are-events-being-missed-and-why-are/58087070#58087070)

Get the events once and use them in multiple loops or pass the list or events to functions and methods where they are handled:

```py
class Ship(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        # [...]
       
        self.ship_image_1 = pygame.image.load('images/ship1.bmp')
        self.ship_image_2 = pygame.image.load('images/ship2.bmp')

    # [...]


    def my_method(self, event_list):

        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.K_1:
                self.image = self.ship_image_1
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
            elif event.type == pygame.K_2:
                self.image = self.ship_image_2
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
```

```py
while run:

    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    my_sprite.my_method(event_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First load the images not in the loop.

```
image1 = pygame.image.load('image1')
image2 = pygame.image.load('image2')
 #replace image 1 with your image
 #in the event loop
 screen.blit(image1, (Your wish dimensions))
 #note that I took screen.blit because I made my screen in a variable called screen.
 #If you variable is display take display.blit
 if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if pygame.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
       image1 = image 2
```