# pygame not blitting images onto the surface permanently

Tags: python, pygame

Okay, so basically I have this code for an adventure game, and when the first cutscene is over, I want the player of the game to press 'enter' and then the code would move to the next bit of the game. but the problem is that, when I try to blit the scene, the scene only shows up for a split second and then goes back to the original scene. I also tried to use a while loop, but that did absolutely nothing compared to when I didn't use it. can someone please explain to me what is going on? I cant figure it out myself, and I've searched for a solution for a while now until i decided to post the question here.

Also here's my code for the main loop of the game:

```
 running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((211, 211, 211))
    # fills the surface with a nice grey color
    alphaval -= 20
    # makes the screen fade into the scene
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    # setting up the timer for the game
    realtime = pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000

    # animations start here
    # cutscene 1
    screen.blit(frame_0, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 320, 480), 15)
    if realtime >= 1:
        loading(337, 99)
    fadein()
    if realtime <= 9 and realtime >= 3:
        channel1.play(pygame.mixer.Sound('missions\call.ogg'))
        time.sleep(9)
    elif realtime >= 9:
        screen.blit(frameE_0, (320, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (320, 0, 320, 480), 15)
    if realtime >= 12.5:
        screen.blit(dialE, (45, 300))
        textbox("hello?", 65, 340)
    if realtime >= 14:
        textbox("who is this?", 125, 340)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and realtime >= 14:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                screen.fill((211, 211, 211))
                screen.blit(frame_0, (0, 0))
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 320, 480), 15)
                screen.blit(frameE_0, (320, 0))
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (320, 0, 320, 480), 15)


    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must draw the scene in the application loop. The event loop is only executed once, when the event occurs. Add a state `draw_scene = 0`. Change the state when the event occurs (`draw_scene = 1`) and draw the scene depending on `draw_scene`.

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. See the documentation:

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. [...]

If `pygame.event.get()` is called in multiple event loops, only one loop receives the events, but never all loops receive all events. As a result, some events appear to be missed.

Get the events once per frame and use them in multiple loops. See [Faster version of 'pygame.event.get()'. Why are events being missed and why are the events delayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086113/faster-version-of-pygame-event-get-why-are-events-being-missed-and-why-are/58087070#58087070)

```py
draw_scene = 0
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((211, 211, 211))
    alphaval -= 20

    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    if draw_scene == 0:
        screen.blit(frame_0, (0, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 320, 480), 15)
        if realtime >= 1:
            loading(337, 99)
        fadein()
        if realtime <= 9 and realtime >= 3:
            channel1.play(pygame.mixer.Sound('missions\call.ogg'))
            time.sleep(9)
        elif realtime >= 9:
            screen.blit(frameE_0, (320, 0))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (320, 0, 320, 480), 15)
        if realtime >= 12.5:
            screen.blit(dialE, (45, 300))
            textbox("hello?", 65, 340)
        if realtime >= 14:
            textbox("who is this?", 125, 340)

        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and realtime >= 14:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    draw_scene = 1

    if draw_scene == 1:
        screen.fill((211, 211, 211))
        screen.blit(frame_0, (0, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 320, 480), 15)
        screen.blit(frameE_0, (320, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (320, 0, 320, 480), 15)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```