# How to get a sprite to disappear when clicked?

Tags: python, pygame

I am doing a balloon popping game and would like the balloons to disappear when clicked. I have an explosion class and an event in the main loop that correctly checks the position of a sprite and then shows an explosion animation if the mouse clicks a balloon. Despite this the original balloon sprite keeps falling down the screen.

HERE IS THE BALLOON CLASS

```
class Balloon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,img):
        super(Balloon,self).__init__()
        self.image=pygame.image.load(img).convert_alpha()
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(40,40))
        self.speed = random.randint(1,4)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x= random.randrange(screen_width)
        self.rect.y= 0
         
    def update(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for sprite in balloongroup:
                    if sprite.rect.collidepoint(pos):
                        self.kill()


        self.rect.y+=self.speed
        if self.rect.bottom >screen_height:
            self.kill()
```

NOW HERE IS THE MAIN LOOP:

```
def start():
    #explosion_group.update()
    
    #explosion_group.empty()
    balloongroup.empty()
    allsprites.empty()
    #basket=createBasket()
    while True:
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                return
        explosion_group.update()
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for sprite in balloongroup:
                if sprite.rect.collidepoint(pos):
                    explosion = Explosion(pos[0], pos[1])
                    explosion_group.add(explosion)
                    allsprites.add(explosion)
                    explosion_group.draw(screen)

                
        screen.fill((0,0,0)) # <--------------- here
        screen.blit(pygame.image.load("background.jpg"),(0,0))
        balloongroup.update()
        if random.randrange(100)<2:
            create_balloon()
        allsprites.draw(screen)
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.update()
```

I thought adding the event in the update method for the balloon class would work but alas it does not. I'm not sure where else to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that your event loop is incorrect. You must handle all the event sin the loop:

```py
def start():
    # [...]

    while True:
        # [...]

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for sprite in balloongroup:
                    if sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        explosion = Explosion(*event.pos)
                        explosion_group.add(explosion)
                        allsprites.add(explosion)
                        explosion_group.draw(screen)

        explosion_group.update()
```

Never call `pygame.event.get()` more than once in the application loop. See [Faster version of 'pygame.event.get()'. Why are events being missed and why are the events delayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086113/faster-version-of-pygame-event-get-why-are-events-being-missed-and-why-are/58087070#58087070).

---

Why don't you show the explosion instead of the sprite? `kill` the sprite when the blast object is created:

```py
def start():
    # [...]

    while True:
        # [...]

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for sprite in balloongroup:
                    if sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):

                        srite.kill()  # <----------

                        explosion = Explosion(event.pos[0], event.pos[1])
                        # [...]
```

---

Alternatively you can `kill` the sprite at the end of the explosion animation. Pass the sprite on to the explosion class and `kill` it when the animation ends:

```py
class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, target):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # [...]

        self.target = target

    def update(self):
        # [...]

        if self.index < len(self.red):
            self.image = self.red[self.index]
        else:
            self.kill()
            self.target.kill()
```

```py
def start():
    # [...]

    while True:
        # [...]

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for sprite in balloongroup:
                    if sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        explosion = Explosion(event.pos[0], event.pos[1], sprite) # <---
```